# App runs locally, fails in PyPi with ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, pypi

I added the `src/sample/run.py` below to the [sampleproject](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject). It runs locally (prints "add_one(2) = 3"), but deployed pip version fails:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ sampleproject-valhuber
sample-run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple'
```

Here is `src/sample/run.py`:

```
import simple  # FAILS in PyPi: ModuleNotFoundError...
def main():
    print("add_one(2) = " + str(simple.add_one(2)))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The complete code, along with packaging procedure is on [this GitHub project](https://github.com/valhuber/sampleproject).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `simple.py` is inside `sample` package. You have to import it from the package:

```
import sample.simple
```

or

```
from sample import simple
```